# Decorated function that locks function?

Tags: python, multithreading

Lets say I have 2 functions that both call a decorator function which takes 2 methods as parameters:

```
def decorator(connector, disconnector):
def decorator(function):
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        print("connecting")
        connector(args[0])
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        print("disconnecting")
        # only want this to be called when function() is completely done
        disconnector(args[0])
        return result
    return decorated_function
return decorator

@decorator(connector, disconnector)
def func1():
   func2()
   print "func2 done"

@decorator(connector, disconnector)
def func2():
   print "hello world"
```

When calling func1(), is there a way to prevent the disconnector method in the decorator from being called until func1() is completely done executing? I don't want func2() call to the decorator to execute the connect/disconnect in this case.

Comment: the code you provided doesn't run

Comment: This is a very odd design. Why would you decorate both functions with the same connector and disconnector if you don't want them called? But addressing your question as asked, maybe you need some state information somewhere else (a singleton? a global?) telling you the number of open connections, so disconnector is only called when that number drops to 0?

Comment: do not decorate func2() and pass argument to funct1() because you have `connector(args[0])`

Answer (score 0):

And if you are looking for func1 completely done before disconnecting do:

```
def connector(*args):
    print("connect done", args[0])
def disconnector(*args):
    print("disconnect done", args[0])


def decorator(connector, disconnector):
    def decorator(function):
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            print("connecting")
            connector(args[0])
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            print("disconnecting")
            # only want this to be called when function() is completely done
            disconnector(args[0])
            return result
        return decorated_function
    return decorator

@decorator(connector, disconnector)
def func1(a):
   func2()
   print("func2 done")

def func2():
   print("hello world")

func1(10)
```

**Output:**

```
connecting
connect done 10
hello world
func2 done
disconnecting
disconnect done 10
```

**Note: Above code is in python3. in your case, you just need to update the print statements in the code(remove parentheses)**

And because you are passing argument to `connector(args[0])`, please pass argument to `func1()`. I have passed a dummy integer=10.